# $H=W$ for weighted Sobolev spaces

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, sobolev-spaces

Meyers and Serrin's $H=W$ is well known, but how does it generalize when we add weights?

Let's define $H^{m,p}(\mu_0,\dots,\mu_m)$ to be the completion of $C^\infty(\Omega)$ in the norm

$$\|u\|_{m,p,\mu_0,\dots,\mu_m}=\int_\Omega \sum_{|I|\le m}\|\partial_Iu\|_{L^p(\mu_{|I|})}, $$

where

$$\|u\|_{L^p(\mu)}^p=\int_\Omega u^pd\mu. $$

Define $W^{m,p}(\mu_0,\dots,\mu_m)$ to be the distributions $u$ on $\Omega$ whose derivatives up to $m$-th order exist in $L^1_{loc}$ and satisfy

$$\|u\|_{m,p,\mu_0,\dots,\mu_m}<\infty. $$

Under what assumptions can we say the two spaces are equal?

If that's too general, $m=1$ and $p=2$ is enough for me.

I'm asking this because I can't quite see the argument for Proposition 1.3 on P271 of Trudinger, *Linear elliptic operators with measurable coefficients*.

FYI, the case when $m=1$ and $\mu_0=\mu_1$ is treated [here](http://dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/118900/CommentatMathUnivCarolRetro_38-1997-1_3.pdf), but the conditions seem very complicated.

**Edit:** missing condition of derivatives in $L^1_{loc}$ added.

Comment: If the case $\mu_0=\mu_1$ looks complicated, the more general case is going to be more complicated. Do you want a full characterization or just examples of sufficient conditions that allow $\mu_0\neq\mu_1$? The assumptions in the paper seem quite standard to me. If you want something simpler, can you specify what that would mean? (And I think that in your definition of $W$ you want the derivatives to exist in $L^1_{loc}$.)

Comment: Just examples covering the $\mu_0\neq\mu_1$ case needed in that paper. Actually I'm unclear if there is any implicit condition on $\mu$ in that proposition.

Comment: @FanZheng As far as I know, the question is very hard. Even in the  case $m=1$ and $\mu_0=\mu_1$, the essential known condition for the coincidence are the so-called $p$-admissible weight, where a kind of reverse H\"older's inequality is the key.

Comment: Then I'm wondering why Trudinger just tossed out that Proposition with no more justification than "the argument of [MS] is still applicable".